# Editing a clique into a k-plex optimally is NP?

Tags: math, graph-theory, complexity-theory, np, clique

A k-plex is a graph in which every vertex is adjacent to all but at most k vertices within the graph. Say I have a complete, undirected, weighted graph (a clique and also a k-plex), and I want to remove some edges, in such a way that the sum of the removed edges is maximized and the property of being a k-plex is mantained.

Is there a polynomial time algorithm to solve this?

I know that in general the k-plex editing is NP-hard when we want to edit the graph in such a way that we find many different k-plexes, but in this case I already know the nodes that will be part of the k-plex so maybe this eases this off?

I tried some greedy edge insertion/deletion strategies but ultimately I can always find a case in which they fail. In this example we want a 3-plex starting from a 5 nodes clique (so we can remove max 2 edges per node).

[image: Base clique]

The greedy algorithm prefers removing one expensive edge rather than 2 less expensive edges. We remove 4 edges and then we cannot continue without breaking the splex constraint.
[image: Solution by greedy removal]

In the optimal solution we remove 5 edges.
[image: Optimal Solution]

Comment: Do you have an example where the simple greedy approach (repeatedly removing the largest weight edge that doesn't break the k-plex property) isn't optimal? Could you add that to your question?

Comment: @Dave I added the example, hope it makes it clear. The main problem is that it looks like that the greedy picking might prefer removing the k most expensive edges rather than a set of edges bigger than k but in sum more expensive.